# why [].anyName gives undefined. but its not true with other Objects like "{}"

Tags: javascript

Steps:
Type in console of chrome:

```
[].anyName
```

This works Fine.
But when we type

```
{}.anyName
```

It gives error.

[image]

Comment: the error that is output gives a strong hint ... {} ... is that an empty code block, or an empty object?

Comment: may be some prototyping issue with `Array` and `Object` constructors.

Comment: I tried both and got undefined in both case but didn't throw any error in output. Could you explain more about your question

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)

Comment: "running" code interactively in the console is probably not the best way to "learn" javascript

Comment: Better to provide more code. Also your question heading is not matching with your question description

Comment: @Satpal - big difference between `{}.anyName` and `alert({}.anyName)` - there's no ambiguity in what `{}` means

Comment: **Added screenshot for reference.**

Comment: @JaromandaX, Yep missed that its block when used in `({})` its empty object

Answer (score 3):

Because {} without context - ie in an assignment or as a parameter to a function, are just a block statement, and they return undefined.

When you enter `{}` to the console and click enter the result is undefined, as this was a block statement that just finished it's work and without an explicit return statement (you can't return from a block statement) returns undefined by default.

When you enter `[]` to the console and click enter the result is [], as this creates a new array.

Comment: {} is a closure? I thought it was an empty block statement

Comment: Yeah, it's not a "closure" in JS terms, you should call it an empty block. Also worth noting that a block can't be within parentheses, which is why `({})` returns an object.

Comment: so the question is, why `[]` creates the array before doing `[].anyName` and `{}` doesn't creates and object before `{}.anyName`?

Comment: The {} is interpreted by context, so if it's alone {}, it's not creating any object because JS decides that it's a block, and not an object literal.

Answer (score -1):

[] this is an array which you can add a methods to the array prototype so when you type [].anyTime it's mean that you want to  search in the array prototype for an anyTime method which does not exist so this will give you an undefined , but you can't access  {}.anyTime in this way cause it is an object and you can access object like this `var obj={}; obj.anyTime`

Comment: {} is not necessarily an object, depends on context, in the questions context it is considered an empty block statement

Comment: he is talking about objects in this question , read the title

Comment: javascript does not interpret code based on what one intends ... read my comment, javascript is interpreting {} as a block statement... no matter how much one wants or wishes or wills it to treat {} as an object in the context that it is being used, javascript will still interpret {} as a block statement **in the context it is being used** in the question